# Spotify output to AirPlay speakers on iPad

Tags: airplay, spotify

I don't see the AirPlay speaker selection gadget on the Spotify IOS client.

1. Is AirPlay support something the App developer must provide explicitly?
2. Is there a way to force the default audio output from an IOS device to an AirPlay speaker at the system level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

D'oh! The AirPlay icon is available in the Spotify client. It is on the *Info* page rather than the top page.  That's where volume control is, too.

Comment: I get lost in the Spotify.app all the time. Just one of those worthless apps you can't get around when you want a specific service.